# Wrong image scaling in html

Tags: html, css

When I place the text in `fieldset` it scales perfectly in the middle when I put the picture in `fieldset` it starts to stretch to the right and the screen goes out. How to make the image also scaled in?

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mmbjzp)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a width to the image and it should fit correctly. Change the image to include a class like:

```
<img class="scaleImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png">
```

Then add the following minimal css:

```
.scaleImage{
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could reduce the width of your picture like follows

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png" alt="Logo no tag line" max="" padding="0" width="70%" height="auto" border="0">
```